# type annotations needed for `&Borrowed`

Tags: rust

I am trying to compile the LeetCode question 98's rust code in https://rustgym.com/leetcode/98
However, I receive an error in this line: `let node = node.borrow();`:

```
type annotations needed for `&Borrowed`
type must be known at this point
rustcE0282
s0098_validate_binary_search_tree.rs(66, 17): consider giving `node` the explicit type `&Borrowed`, where the type parameter `Borrowed` is specified
```

However, Leetcode has no problem to compile it. Here is the Code.

```
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::cell::RefCell;
type TreeLink = Option<Rc<RefCell<TreeNode>>>;
trait Inorder {
    fn inorder(&self, visit: &mut dyn FnMut(i32));
}
impl Inorder for TreeLink {
    fn inorder(&self, visit: &mut dyn FnMut(i32)) {
        if let Some(node) = self {
            let node = node.borrow();
            Self::inorder(&node.left, visit);
            visit(node.val);
            Self::inorder(&node.right, visit);
        }    
    }
}

impl Solution {
    pub fn is_valid_bst(root: TreeLink) -> bool {
        let mut prev: Option<i32> = None;
        let mut res = true;
        root.inorder(&mut |x| {
            if let Some(y) = prev {
                if x <= y {
                    res = false;
                }
            }
            prev = Some(x);
        });
        res
    }
}
```

I am using rustc 1.55.0 (c8dfcfe04 2021-09-06). I think it may be a bug in compiler.

Comment: I am not leetcode but I can't compile that code either, as TreeNode and Solution are undefined. also the code you posted here is not like the code in the article you linked.

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [mre]. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here.

Comment: Ccheck if you have imported the `Borrow` trait and remove that import. Sometimes Clion incorrectly auto-imports that when I type `some_ref-cell.borrow()` and this error appears

Answer (score 6):

1. Your code is fine. I passed 98' by you code without any change.
   [image]
2. I met the same question by adding the redundant code `use std::borrow::Borrow;`. So when I deleted `use std::borrow::Borrow;`, everything is fine~ 
   [image]

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, after I checked, the culprit was the "clion" error auto-import, try to delete the "import" section and re-import, the problem should be solved.

Comment: Uff, VSCode does the same, I presume it comes from the underlying `rust-analyzer`. It's this import that needs deleting: `use std::borrow::{BorrowMut, Borrow};`

Answer (score 0):

The solution https://rustgym.com/leetcode/98 use rustgym_util::*; with define TreeNode, TreeLink, etc.

```
struct Solution;
//
//--Begin rustgym_util:: def----------------------------------
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq, PartialOrd, Ord)]
pub struct TreeNode {
    pub val: i32,
    pub left: TreeLink,
    pub right: TreeLink,
}
pub type TreeLink = Option<Rc<RefCell<TreeNode>>>;

#[macro_export]
macro_rules! tree {
    ($e:expr) => {
        TreeLink::leaf($e)
    };
    ($e:expr, $l:expr, $r:expr) => {
        TreeLink::branch($e, $l, $r)
    };
}

use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::rc::Rc;

pub trait TreeMaker {
    fn branch(val: i32, left: TreeLink, right: TreeLink) -> TreeLink {
        Some(Rc::new(RefCell::new(TreeNode { val, left, right })))
    }
    fn leaf(val: i32) -> TreeLink {
        Some(Rc::new(RefCell::new(TreeNode {
            val,
            left: None,
            right: None,
        })))
    }
}

impl TreeMaker for TreeLink {}
//
//--Endrustgym_util:: def----------------------------------

trait Inorder {
    fn inorder(&self, visit: &mut dyn FnMut(i32));
}

impl Inorder for TreeLink {
    fn inorder(&self, visit: &mut dyn FnMut(i32)) {
        if let Some(node) = self {
            let node = node.borrow();
            Self::inorder(&node.left, visit);
            visit(node.val);
            Self::inorder(&node.right, visit);
        }
    }
}

impl Solution {
    fn is_valid_bst(root: TreeLink) -> bool {
        let mut prev: Option<i32> = None;
        let mut res = true;
        root.inorder(&mut |x| {
            if let Some(y) = prev {
                if x <= y {
                    res = false;
                }
            }
            prev = Some(x);
        });
        res
    }
}

#[test]
fn test() {
    let root = tree!(2, tree!(1), tree!(3));
    let res = true;
    assert_eq!(Solution::is_valid_bst(root), res);
    let root = tree!(5, tree!(1), tree!(4, tree!(3), tree!(6)));
    let res = false;
    assert_eq!(Solution::is_valid_bst(root), res);
}
```

How you have defined TreeNode in your side?

Answer (score -4):

It is very strange. Today I compile again without any changes. Now the issue is gone. I think it may be caused by a hidden bug in rust compiler. Thank you for your help!