# How to get `&mut T` of a Box<Rc<RefCell<T>>>?

Tags: rust

I got a  `Box<Rc<RefCell<T>>>` from FFI. How can I get the `&mut T` based on it?

I can not compile it. Compiler tells me:

```
47 |     let mut r: &mut Server = server.borrow_mut();
   |                                     ^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `BorrowMut<Server>` is not implemented for `Box<Rc<RefCell<Server>>>`
   |
   = help: the trait `BorrowMut<T>` is implemented for `Box<T, A>`
```

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Server {
    id: i32,
}

impl Server {
    pub fn change_id(&mut self) {
        self.id = self.id + 1;
    }
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn server_change_id(server: *mut Rc<RefCell<Server>>) -> isize {
    let server: Box<Rc<RefCell<Server>>> = unsafe { Box::from_raw(server) };
    let mut r: &mut Server = server.borrow_mut();
    r.change_id();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Auto-deref will make `borrow_mut()` directly accessible.

```rust
use std::{cell::RefCell, cell::RefMut, ops::DerefMut, rc::Rc};

fn main() {
    let a = Box::new(Rc::new(RefCell::new("aaa".to_owned())));
    //
    println!("{:?}", a);
    {
        let mut r: RefMut<String> = a.borrow_mut();
        r.push_str("bbb"); // via RefMut
        let r2: &mut String = r.deref_mut();
        r2.push_str("ccc"); // via exclusive-reference
    }
    println!("{:?}", a);
}
/*
RefCell { value: "aaa" }
RefCell { value: "aaabbbccc" }
*/
```

In your code, `let mut r = server.borrow_mut();` should be enough to invoke `r.change_id()`.

```rust
    let mut r = server.borrow_mut();
    r.change_id();
```

If you absolutely want a `&mut`, then use `let r2 = r.deref_mut()` and invoke `r2.change_id()`.

```rust
    let mut r = server.borrow_mut();
    let r2 = r.deref_mut();
    r2.change_id();
```

Comment: thanks @prog-fh, but my code always show error. I modified my codes, would you please have a look on it?

Comment: @progquester look at the types. `RefMut` is a kind of proxy holding the exclusive reference. You can explicitly access the reference if you want to, but it is generally not needed.

Comment: thank you very much. The above code can compile in normal code block. But when it is a ffi export no_mangle function, it can not compile. very strange.

Comment: @progquester can you show the error message?

Comment: 47 |     let mut r: &mut Server = server.borrow_mut();
   |                                     ^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `BorrowMut<Server>` is not implemented for `Box<Rc<RefCell<Server>>>`
   |
   = help: the trait `BorrowMut<T>` is implemented for `Box<T, A>`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.

Comment: Very strange, it seems that the compiler can not determine the right type of the server.

Comment: @progquester I repeat, the problem comes from the type annotation; just remove it. `borrow_mut()` returns a `RefMut`. Either you use it as is, or you use `deref_mut()` to obtain the `&mut` (see my edited answer)

Comment: thank you very much. Can you show me the full code?

Comment: @progquester it is in my answer from the beginning.(refresh the page?) In the code you posted, just remove `: &mut Server`

Comment: thanks. But if the annotation removed, error says: error[E0282]: type annotations needed for `&mut Borrowed`
  --> src/main.rs:44:15
   |
44 |     let r = a.borrow_mut();
   |         -     ^^^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type for type parameter `Borrowed` declared on the trait `BorrowMut`
   |         |
   |         consider giving `r` the explicit type `&mut Borrowed`, where the type parameter `Borrowed` is specified

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247239/discussion-between-progquester-and-prog-fh).

Comment: Problem is caused by unused improt "std::borrow::Borrow", after delete it, it can compile. Here is a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69216874/type-annotations-needed-for-borrowed

Answer (score -1):

T gets wrapped inside the `RefCell<T>` must implement the `Deref` or `DerefMut` trait in order to be borrowed mutably or reference borrowed. In your case, Server must implement a `deref` method.

```
use std::ops::DerefMut;

impl DerefMut for Server {

    fn deref_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Self {
        *self // this assumes your server has more than just one i32 field.
    }
}
```

After this implementation, you should be able to call `server.borrow_mut()` should work perfectly and return you a mutable server object.

Comment: I don't think this answer is correct at all. `deref_mut()` doesn't need to be explicitly implemented by a `T` held in a `RefCell<T>`. Instead, `deref_mut()` is [already implemented](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefMut.html#impl-DerefMut) by the `RefMut` type returned by `RefCell::borrow_mut()`.